# Javascript not included play framework

Tags: javascript, java, html, playframework

I'm working on a website with play framework and I have a little problem.

I am using a main.scala.html page which includes a `<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery.js")"></script>`
Then to create a page I use `@main("pagename") {body content here}`
The problem is that when I start the webserver it doesn't include the javascript file. It does work for the CSS however: `<link href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")" rel="stylesheet">`

This is showing in chrome developer tool:

[image]

The jquery.js is located in: /public/javascripts/jquery.js

Does somebody know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: check and make sure your jquery.js and folder javascript is located in public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the script tags inside the body now and it works. Don't know why it doesnt work when I put it in the main.